# Nvidia GEforce gtx 960m graphics

Tags: 17.04, nvidia-geforce

Ubuntu 17.04
I have a new Asus with a Nvidia GEforce gtx 960m graphics.
I have dual boot with windows 10 and grub.
I've tried anything I could get my hands on askubuntu or net, namely working with acpi and/or nouveau.modeset in grub.
The driver simply doesn't work and the reboot/shutdown either.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: Disable Secure Boot in BIOS.

Comment: And install the correct driver version.

Comment: Solved this issue by:  1) Disable Secure Boot in BIOS 2) install the correct driver version 3) edit the /etc/default/grub file: 
sudo vi /etc/default/grub

Change the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" line to the following:

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""

Save the file, then run sudo update-grub Then reboot, and it worked for me.

Comment: @PedroSilva What was the correct version of the driver you used? I would like to know also for myself for my machine.